# Accessing a mobile users phone number

Tags: html, mobile

When a user is browsing a mobile site, I'd like to pre-populate the phone number field of a form with the phone number of that mobile device. Is that possible with a plan old html5 site?

Comment: No. Potential security risk.

Comment: I kind of assumed that would be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile phone number is not provided to the requesting website. That would be a privacy nightmare if it was provided.

Some operators, however, provides a mobile subscriber number (which is different than the actual mobile number), which is used by the operator web services.